# How do I set Realtime Shadow Colour through script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change the Realtime Shadow Colour, which can be seen in the Lighting window under the Scene tab.

Now, I can change it in the editor, but I seemingly can't for the life of me figure out how to change it through a script during runtime.

I have tried changing RenderSettings.subtractiveShadowColor, but turned out it wasn't the one.

Suggestions/solutions are appreciated.

[image: Screenshot showing the mentioned variable]

Comment: Could you please post the code you used when testing `RenderSettings.subtractiveShadowColor`? There may have been a mistake which prevented that line from running.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter that setting by using [RenderSettings.subtractiveShadowColor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-subtractiveShadowColor.html), you simply set that value to a [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) like so:

```
RenderSettings.subtractiveShadowColor = colourValue;
```

Additionally the [RenderSettings](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings.html) class is where you'll find most of the variables that are displayed in that window as well.

Comment: It looks like OP tried this already but it didn't work. *"I have tried changing `RenderSettings.subtractiveShadowColor`, but turned out it wasn't the one."*....

Comment: That is curious, I shall attempt to replicate this case locally and see how it reacts.

Comment: Locally I was able to change the subtractive shadow colour using the solution I wrote above in an empty project, it would appear that the issue is something else. Here was the code that worked successfully. https://pastebin.com/42MzUegD

Comment: I agree with you too. That should work. I am simply pointing out that OP mentioned he had tried this but you put that exact thing that didn't work for him as answer. An answer with possible reasons why this is not working is fine. At this time, it will be better for OP to show his actual code. Maybe that will show what he's doing wrong